# The matrix M with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse

> Let $B$ be a matrix of order $3$ with $\det(B) = -5$
>
> Does there exist an invertible matrix $M^{-1}$ with real entries where $M = 4 B M^{-1}$?

I am very confused because I thought I had to verify that $\det(M) \not= 0$. So I computed $\det(M) =  det(4 B M^{-1}) = 4^3 \det(B) \frac{1}{\det(M)}$. I got $\det(M) = \sqrt{-320}$. So the answer might be simply NO because $\det(M)$ is not a real value, so we might find complex value entries, right?

Comment: You right, the answer is no. In any matrix, after row operations you get a triangular matrix and determinant is actually product of the pivots of that triangular matrix (if there is no need for permutation, otherwise you add (-1)^n as a factor). This number is always real. Another view, determinant is the constant term of the characteristic poly. of the matrix. That pol. is real polyn. So det is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $M = 4 B M^{-1}$ is equivalent to $M^2 = 4B$. As you noticed, it is not possible to find a real matrix $M$ satisfying such equation as it implies

$$(\det M)^2 = -320.$$

However, the equation has at least one solution in term of complex matrix using [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition). See this [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Solutions_in_closed_form) for more details.